# Intellij method parameter openjdk

Tags: intellij-idea, java

I am using Linux Mint with IntelliJ and OpenJDK8. On Windows I can remember that IntelliJ showed the parameter names like in the API doc.

Now I just get some short names like `s`, `l` or `i`, etc.

Example:
`Thread.sleep`: the hints should be

```
sleep(long millis); and  
sleep(long millis, int nanos);
```

But they are currently

```
sleep(long l); and  
sleep(long l, int i);
```

like you can see in the picture.

In the project structure, the documentation path is already set to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/.

Is this a problem with OpenJDK?

[image: Parameter Name]

Comment: Are you sure you installed the Java sources? This might be an extra package on Linux Mint. Edit: Check if `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip` is available in the file system.

Comment: yes, this archive is already in that folder...

Answer (score 1):

I solved that issue: 
First I installed the openjdk-8-source. Seems like the archive was only a link to a non existing dir. Now it points to ../openjdk-8/src.zip.
After that in the Project Structure in IntelliJ - Platform Settings - SDKs the Sourcepath tab was empty. So I added path to the src.zip dir.